# Facebook send message to page from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How i can send message to any Facebook page using JavaScript?

I am using following code but its giving me error:

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            to: "",
            name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
            link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
        });
```

> API Error Code: 1 API Error Description: An unknown error occurred
>   Error Message: kError 1545014: Invalid Recipients: One or more of your
>   recipients are not valid. Please try again.

I can send message to users using above code but how i can find the "TO" in case of page?

In case of send message button, where i can mention my page ID?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button

Thanks

Comment: The Send dialog is to send stuff to friends, not pages. You could embed the Page plugin, that has a tab people can use to send a message to a page.

Comment: can you please provide help link?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+page+plugin

Answer (score -2):

Page plugin of facebook works:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

```
<div class="fb-page"
     data-href="Page_URL"
     data-tabs="messages"
     data-width="380"
     data-hide-cover="false"
     data-show-facepile="false"
     data-show-posts="false"></div>
```

Comment: "from javascript" ... thats not javascript